# get all methods and properties of an object

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

If I use (on a text frame):

```
b.selection().fit(FitOptions.frameToContent);
```

Then it works as expected, this means that the selected object has a fit method.

If I use:

```
for (var property in b.selection()) {
    b.println(property);
}
```

On the same selection then it doesn't print a fit method.

If I use this:

```
function getMethods(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var id in obj) {
    try {
      if (typeof(obj[id]) == "function") {
        result.push(id + ": " + obj[id].toString());
      }
    } catch (err) {
      result.push(id + ": inaccessible");
    }
  }
  return result;
}


b.println(getMethods(b.selection()));
```

Then I don't get the fit method either. And I would really like to know all methods and properties of the selected object. So how do i get them?

Answer (score 2):

try `obj.reflect.methods` to get all methods

Answer (score 1):

When method `fit()` exists and doesn't shine up in the `for-in-loop` it is a **non-enumerable** property.

There are different ways to access the properties of an object:

```
var obj = b.selection();
for (var p in obj) {
    console.log(p); // --> all enumerable properties of obj AND its prototype
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(p) {
    console.log(p); // --> all enumerable OWN properties of obj, NOT of its prototype
});
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(p) {
    console.log(p); // all enumerable AND non-enumerable OWN properties of obj, NOT of its prototype
});
```

If you don't find `.fit()` on one of this ways its **not enumerable** AND **not OWN** property of obj, but sits somewhere in the **prototype** of obj. Then you can do:

```
var prot = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prot).forEach(function(pp) {
    console.log(pp); // --> all enumerable AND non-enumerable properties of obj's prototype
});
```

Often objects have a bit longer **prototype-chain** and the property sits somewhere deeper on it. Then you just repeat the last snippet as often as needed:

```
var prot2 = Object.getPrototypeOf(prot);
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prot2).forEach( /*...*/ );
```

To make it complete: Let's say you have found `.fit` on the obj's prototype `prot`. Then you can inspect it:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prot.fit));
```

That outputs an object which shows the *value* of `prot.fit` and whether it's *enumerable, writable, and configurable* or not. The Object.methods and some more [FIND HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Answer (score 1):

Or just use `b.inspect(obj)`. Prints out all properties and values of an object in a recursive manner to the console. See http://basiljs.ch/reference/#inspect